# Using Httpclient for send SOAP request In Asp.net Core

Tags: web-services, soap, asp.net-core, asmx

Im using  Asp.net Core, for calling an `asmx service` which has 4 methods and i want to call one of them by the name: `Verify` method, i do this steps:

1-Create realted `SOAP`:

```
     private XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(PayVM  payModel)
     {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
            string requiredXML = string.Format(@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema""><SOAP-ENV:Body><verifyTransaction xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/""> <String_1 xsi:type=""xsd:string"">{0}</String_1><String_2 xsi:type=""xsd:string"">{1}</String_2></verifyTransaction></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>", payModel.ReNO, payModel.MID);
            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(requiredXML);
            return soapEnvelop;
     }
```

2-create the `HttpClient` and send my request:

```
            XmlDocument soapRequest = CreateSoapEnvelope(iPGVerifyResultModel);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("relatedUri/ServiceName.asmx"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post
                };

                request.Content = new StringContent(soapRequest.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

                request.Headers.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "Verify"); //I want to call this method 

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                Task<Stream> streamTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                Stream stream = streamTask.Result;
                var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                var soapResponse = XDocument.Load(sr);
               //do some other stuff...
            }
```

but i didn't result, i try uses service by same parameters with `Soap UI` and the service work properly, but in my way i got `StatusCode: 400` what is the problem?